# My TCP servr was killed with WSACancelBlockingCall?

Tags: c++, sockets, visual-c++, tcp

I have simple TCP server that is lessening for connections.

```
UINT  MTServerThread(LPVOID pParam)
{       

    FILELog::ReportingLevel() = logINFO;


    WSADATA wsaData;
    sockaddr_in local;
    int wsaret=WSAStartup(0x101,&wsaData);
    if(wsaret!=0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    local.sin_family=AF_INET;
    local.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;
    local.sin_port=htons((u_short)20248);
    server=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if(server==INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if(bind(server,(sockaddr*)&local,sizeof(local))!=0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if(listen(server,10)!=0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    SOCKET client;
    sockaddr_in from;
    int fromlen=sizeof(from);

    while(true)
    {
        FILE_LOG(logINFO)<<"connecting";
        client=accept(server,(struct sockaddr*)&from,&fromlen);
        if (client==INVALID_SOCKET) 
            {
                int g = WSAGetLastError();

            FILE_LOG(logINFO)<<"invalid socket code "<<g;
            }
        AfxBeginThread(ClientThread,(LPVOID)client);    
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

I need to use third party compiled DLL library that is also making its own tcp communication not related to my server and acts like client. After creating library class object and using it for some procedures that are related to its own (library) TCP comunication I have breakpoint dropped on line `int g = WSAGetLastError();`. Result of last error is 10004.

That means:

```
WSAEINTR
10004
Interrupted function call.
A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall.
```

Is it possible that code in dll can affect my TCP server? I have dll source code, but I cant't find call to `WSACancelBlockingCall` in it.

How to start to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Winsock 1.1 and `WSACancelBlockingCall()` does apply to that version of Winsock.  But since you cannot find `WSACancelBlockingCall()` in the DLL source code, then obviously it not actually using it.

Try updating your app to use Winsock 2.0+ instead (just change your first parameter to `WSAStartup()`) and see if the problem goes away.  `WSACancelBlockingCall()` was removed in Winsock 2.0.

If you are still encountering the problem, then the most likely culprit is a firewall/antivirus program running on your machine and interfering with the connection.

BTW, you should not be calling `AfxBeginThread()` if `accept()` fails, since there is no connection for your thread to manage.

Comment: I have tested with winsock 2.2 version, but got the same result. I have tested this project on two machines, non of them has antivirus installed. I don't think this is antivirus issue, because if I not create dll class object program runs fine

Comment: What about a firewall?  Did you rule that out?

Comment: I have tested with turned off firewall

Comment: I have looked at the source of dll and looks I found problem. Dll calls WSACleanup() at loading time without calling WSAStartup at first. Situation looks following. My app calls WSAStartup and runs TCP service and DLL calls WSACleanup() at loading time and kills my TCP service